# Getting too few arguments to function call, and conflicting types C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int max;
char line[MAXLINE];
char longest[MAXLINE];

int getline(void);
void copy(void);

int main(){
  int len;
  extern int max;
  extern char longest[];

  max = 0;
  while((len = getline()) > 0){
    if(len > max){
      max = len;
      copy();
    }
  }
  if(max > 0)
    printf("%s", longest);
  return 0;
}

int getline(void){
  int c, i;
  extern char line[];

  for(i = 0; i < MAXLINE - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n'; i++)
    line[i] = c;
  if(c == '\n'){
    line[i] = c;
    i++;
  }
  line[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}

void copy(void){
  int i;
  extern char line[], longest[];

  i = 0;
  while((longest[i] = line[i]) != '\0')
    i++;
}
```

The errors that appear are:

```
longlineextern.c:9:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(void);
    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __lineca...
        ^
longlineextern.c:18:24: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3,
      have 0
  while((len = getline()) > 0){
               ~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:1: note: 'getline' declared here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __lineca...
^
longlineextern.c:29:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(void){
    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:448:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __lineca...
        ^
3 errors generated.
```

This has also happened on other programs and I cannot see why as I am passing in the correct amount of arguments and they are of the correct type.

The Program is copied exactly from the C Programming Language book, so it should be correct.

It was compiled using gcc in the Mac terminal

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Because `getline` already exists in the library you are using, name conflicts are occurring. Use a different name like `my_getline` etc.

Comment: The is no `getline` in MSVC's `stdio.h` and it compiles cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because there is already a `getline` function defined in `stdio.h`.

Defining a function with the same name but different argument types is known as [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), but this is not allowed in C.

You should call the function something else to avoid the name conflict, such as `my_getline`.